# Android Handshake Error in ADT

Tags: android, eclipse

I am developing a mobile app that can print a invoice from Bluetooth printer(Model : VPT801). I received the sample code from manufacturer and when i run it with eclipse IDE it can print the invoice. After export it to android project and ran it using Android development studio. But it was not working when i run with Android development studio.

I found the codes which was getting error as mention below.

```
Sys.Lib_HandShake();

Sys.Lib_GetVersion(version);
```

Sys is a class which is included in the third party jar file.

I tried with same mobile phone running Android 4.2.2. by using two IDE

Please help me to solve this problem.